# Spock framework NPE issue with IntelliJ

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, spock

I have this issue running my spock tests in my IntelliJ:

```
Groovyc: While compiling [tests of global-tournaments-api-server]:
  Could not instantiate global transform class 
    org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform specified at
    jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/spockframework/spock-core/2.2-M1-groovy-3.0/spock-core-2.2-M1-groovy-3.0.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation
  because of exception java.lang.NullPointerException:
    Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toString()"
    because the return value of "java.security.CodeSource.getLocation()" is null
```

Do you know what could be the root problem?

Comment: Is it possible to compile files outside IDE?

Comment: @y.bedrov thanks,  if I run `groovy test.groovy` I have some errors like: ```unable to resolve class spock.lang.Specification
 @ line 7, column 1.
   import spock.lang.Specification```

Comment: Please share the full stacktrace.

Comment: The error might come from `GroovyReleaseInfo#getArtifactPath` or `SpockReleaseInfo#getArtifactPath` where `*ReleaseInfo.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString()` is being returned. That does not replace a stack trace, but might be a starting point for Leonard's usually spot-on educated guesses.

Comment: Guys, I still have the same issue abode. I can't run any spock tests for that error. I have checked the dependency tree and I am using those dependencies: +- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test
org.spockframework:spock-core:jar:2.1-groovy-3.0:test
org.spockframework:spock-junit4:jar:2.1-groovy-3.0:test
 org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-sql:jar:3.0.1:compile
org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:jar:0.7.1:compile

Comment: Do you know how to use groovy and spock in a spring boot app?